# Does SQL Server allow Multi table clustering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clustered-index

My question is simple.

Does SQL Server allow Multi table clustering?

Comment: Maybe like how Oracle table clusters work? "A table cluster is a group of tables that share the same data blocks, since they share common columns and are often used together. When you create cluster tables, Oracle physically stores all rows for each table in the same data blocks." http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tip_hash_index_cluster_table.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - SQL Server has the concept of clusters in which two or instances of SQL Server (the program) is running (or is available to run) and if one fails the other instance can very rapidly take over. They work on the same data which is stored in a shared drive. But only one is active at a time.